# Initializing Angular with Server Side Data from ASP.Net Core

Tags: angular, .net-core, single-page-application

I have an Angular12/.Net_Core application that I need to initialize with some information from the server only at the first load of the Angular app, and not on every request. I don't want to use Server Side Rendering that's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#pass-data-from-net-code-into-typescript-code) due to its drawbacks.

Are there any other techniques to achieve that?

Comment: I don't know the use-case, but you can consider localStorage. Set some values before serving the Angular app. I've used this approach in some cases.

Comment: Can .net core set values in the localstorage for Angular to read?

Answer (score 0):

You can use application initializer and store the data. This way app will wait for your data to be fetched only on the first start, later on you can get it from the local storage.

https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: Thanks, but makes Angular to be pulling the data from the server while instead, I want the server to initialize angular with some data. (e.g. the language the page should load in. )

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER is clear and widely used for exact such purposes - to init the data. What you want to do is to modify application resources on the fly on the webserver and has little to nothing with angular itself.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Doesn't APP_INITIALIZER execute at the browser? if so, it won't be helpful because I need to have the server data available by the time APP_INITIALIZER is executing without the need to do an extra api call to the server to get that data. I hope that makes sense